# Dynamic Pages Nuxt Google SEO

Tags: nuxt.js

I've had my site crawled and indexed by Google. But ~ only the homepage with the basic content that is static. My app loads reddit data and displays it to the user in a `async fetch()` call. It looks to me that Google isn't rendering that command or waiting for it.

I've tried `nuxt generate` with `target:static` though this is only generating the static `routes`. Is there something I need to do here to allow the data to be rendered by Google or just await them to crawl it with Javascript?

Thanks

Comment: Generate your website, preview the built app, go to a dynamic page, disable JS. Do you see your static content?

Comment: Nope. Just a ton of `File Not Found` JS errors. :/

Comment: Mostly, trying to call the local API. Doesn't fetch or render the API response.

Comment: What is a local API for you? Also, you're probably doing something wrong if you have some JS errors. Mind sharing more context here?

Comment: It's the proxy of the reddit api, fixing the cors issue. It loads the site fine, though seems to be constantly on loading with `fetch` when loading the page.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's not a **local** API so but a proxy (still reaches Internet). Do you have a public github repo or far more context as of what is happening here (hard to debug as of right now)?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not public. But the main issue is, it looks like the proxy API calls aren't working when doing target:static. Though, as it's an infinite number of pages from the reddit API - would static even be an option? Or am I going to have to go down `asyncData` and block the loading of the page until the data comes through?

Comment: Yeah, to have a proxy you need a server, hence only target: server is viable. Why do you even want to have a local clone of Reddit? SSG is indeed not suitable, while SSR will be pretty hard to handle too. Still, Nuxt does not make SSR per-page, just on initial render.

Comment: Just testing my knowledge really and learning Nuxt. Interesting, so essentially if fetching from an API and want some real SEO value. It's going to have to be `asyncData` instead of `fetch`?